# Manipulating ComboBox items

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox, itemlistener

I am trying to create a code that calculates the student's GPA using two comboBox that holds grades and units.
grade

```
String [] grade = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
```

unit

```
String[] unit = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};
```

For each course there will be a corresponding comboBox `comboGrade` and `comboUnit` components holding the values of the array `grade` and `unit` respectively. Given that there will be 10 courses, the comboBox `grade` and `unit` will be 10 each. I managed this using two `ArrayList` `ArrayList<JComboBox> courseGrade;` and `ArrayList<JComboBox> courseUnit;` to hold the 10 comboBoxes using the following code:

```
//grade
    String[] grades = {"A","B","C","D","E","F"};
        courseGrade = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            JComboBox comboGrade = new JComboBox(grade);
        courseGrade.add(comboUnit); //adds the comboBox to the ArrayList
    }

    //unit
    String[] unit = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};
        courseUnit = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            JComboBox comboUnit = new JComboBox(unit);
        courseUnit.add(comboUnit); //adds the comboBox to the ArrayList
    }
```

I got the selected item using this `ItemListener`:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt){
    String item;
    if (evt.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        item = (String) evt.getItem();
```

for each of the `comboBox` and then added it to a new `ArrayList` `ArrayList<Integer> gradeSelected;`

```
switch (item) {
                        case "A":
                            gradeSelected.add(A);
                            break;
                        case "B":
                            gradeSelected.add(B);
                            break;
                        case "C":
                            gradeSelected.add(C);
                            break;
                        case "D":
                            gradeSelected.add(D);
                            break;
                        case "E":
                            gradeSelected.add(E);
                            break;
                        case "F":
                            gradeSelected.add(F);
                            break;
                    }
```

where `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` are integer constants representing 5,4,3,2,1,0 respectively

Now here is my problem....

What if the user DESELECTS the SELECTED item and then selects a new item from the comboBox ?

```
//I thought of `ItemEvent.DESLECTED`;
```

How do i respond to such event? given that once the user has already selected an item it has been added to the `ArrayList` "`gradeSelected`". How do i remove the already added item and replace it with the current selection in exactly the same

index as the previous selection?

Perhaps am approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: Simplest solution is to use a button press to calculate the grades once all the values are selected, otherwise your design becomes slightly more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Good point sir, i did add a checkbox that the user can check after selecting the values but that becomes extra work for the user.

Comment: Better them than you!!! :), no not really, it is always better to have a simpler design that others can understand while maintaining it and is simpler to implement and it also makes clear to user how the software works and that a input is necessary to initiate an action

Comment: Good advice, but is there any way i could make the code above work?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ironluca, don't register the user's input until he is done making all of his selections and is ready to submit his selections, and so thus I think that the best solution is to allow your GUI to be changeable and to have none of the inputs be binding until the user performs an action that causes the input to be submitted. This could be on the press of a submit button, or on trying to advance to a next view of your GUI or on trying to close a dialog window. It doesn't matter so much what this step is, so long as it is easily recognizable for the user. At this point your data should be validated, and the program should proceed to the next step based on whether the inputted data has been deemed to be valid and complete or not.

Otherwise if you wanted to be able to remove items from a collection on deselection, you could always use a Stack for your collection such as a LinkedList, and then push and pop items on the stack as they are added or removed.

Also, rather than a switch statement, consider consolidating your grade information, the letter and the number, into an enum. Something like:

```
public enum Grade {
   A("A", 5), B("B", 4), C("C", 3), D("D", 2), E("E", 1), F("F", 0);

   private String text;
   private int value;

   private Grade(String text, int value) {
      this.text = text;
      this.value = value;
   }

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return text;
   }
}
```

Then it could be used easily:

```
  JComboBox<Grade> gradeCombo = new JComboBox<>(Grade.values());
  gradeCombo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gradeCombo);

  Grade grade = (Grade) gradeCombo.getSelectedItem();
  if (grade != null) {
     System.out.printf("Grade is %s with a value of %d%n", grade, grade.getValue());
  }
```

Comment: I'm starting to see the whole picture here. Getting the user to validate his selections seems plausible and i think i'll adapt to that. Thanks.